# Animation in cell background cancels interaction

Tags: ios, uitableview

I change the background color of a cell in a tableview using an animation to create a sort of pulsating effect. The animation is running fine, but I am not able to select the cell anymore. It looks like the animation cancels the user interaction. Cells that don't have the animation are still clickable.

My code:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.105882F green:0.564706F blue:0.243137F alpha:1.0F];
    //playerCardsTable.userInteractionEnabled = YES;???
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.105882F green:0.564706F blue:0.243137F alpha:0.2F];}
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

As you can see I also tried the userInteractionEnabled, with no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it. However, I am not really happy with the animation. The animation is not running in sync, so all cells animate in a different rhythm, so the speak. Happen to know something for that, or is caused by the redrawing of the cells while scrolling the tableview?

Comment: Hmmm, my first thought is trying to sync them to some sort of timestamp system but I'm not really sure. I'll let you know if something comes to me.